# Can I ask a candidate who rejected us about his offer?

Tags: work-environment, salary, working-conditions

Is it professional behavior or OK to ask my close friend who didn't accept an offer from our company about some details of the offer (ex. the conditions or the salary)?

Comment: If that's a close friend, you'd know better.

Comment: @Sak: In my mind, this is not clearly workplace related, so I'm not sure if the community will think this is appropriate for our site.  However, I've edited the question in an effort to make it easier to understand.  If I changed the meaning or you don't like my edits for another reason, feel free to rollback to your original question or make more [edits](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/10765/edit) that improve the question.

Comment: If the situation were reversed, would the company tell a candidate why they weren't offered a position?

Comment: @GreenMatt thanks very much for your effort, but I mean he rejected but not the company.

Comment: Yes or No questions do not do well on SE.  What is the problem you are trying to solve here?  Why are you concerned about the friend not accepting?  Are you a manager or is it just you were hoping to work with your friend?

Comment: I think this is a great question at core - because this is an issue a ton of people will face and one a lot of people have. I suggest making the question more, "how should I handle a close friend rejecting a job offer with my company?" but otherwise a great question.

Comment: @Sak: I don't understand what you're trying to ask.  Please edit to make the quesiton more understandable.

Comment: Sak, I've cleaned up the wordinng of your question; the title and body seemed to have two different questions. If this is not the question you want to ask, please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is nothing to stop you asking your friend about his offer. As a representative of your company there is also nothing to stop you asking someone who rejects an offer from you about the reasons - although I would be prepared for a likely refusal.

The major issue is getting the roles of 'friend' and 'representitive of your company' mixed up. **If you ask your friend as a friend, you should absolutely not pass that information on to your company unless he specifically agrees to it.**

Answer (score 1):

The problem I have with this question is that you're crossing two worlds: your personal life and your professional life.

On the professional side, if you're not the representative that gave him the interviews and gave him the offer to say yay or nay to, you shouldn't ask for reasons simply because it's none of your business.

On the personal side, he's your friend and you have the right to ask your friend why he turned down any job offer, whether it's to be supportive for his reasons to decline or to condemn him to 20 lashes for turning down a potentially amazing offer.

I think the average Joe would just ask anyways. It's human nature to wonder about the decisions of our friends and loved ones.